# python program very slow

Tags: python, performance, python-itertools, words

This program generates letter combinations and checks to see if they are words, but the program is extremely slow generating only a few words a second. please tell me why it is very slow, and what i need to make it faster

```
import itertools 

for p1 in itertools.combinations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 4):
    with open('/Users/kyle/Documents/english words.txt') as word_file:
        english_words = set(word.strip().lower() for word in word_file)

    def is_english_word(word):
        return word.lower() in english_words

    print ''.join(p1),"is", is_english_word(''.join(p1))
```

Comment: how big is your words list? You are reading it once per combination.

Comment: The words list is a list of all English words.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is slow because you are re-reading a file *for each loop iteration*, and create a new function object. Neither of these two things are dependent on the loop variable; move these out of the loop to only run *once*.

Furthermore, the simple function can be inlined; calling a function is relatively expensive. And don't call `''.join()` twice, either. And you are only using lowercase letters to generate the words, so `.lower()` is redundant:

```
with open('/Users/kyle/Documents/english words.txt') as word_file:
    english_words = set(word.strip().lower() for word in word_file)

for p1 in itertools.combinations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 4):
    word = ''.join(p1)
    print '{} is {}'.format(word, word in english_words)
```

Since you are generating words of length 4, you could save yourself some memory by only loading words of length 4 from your english words file:

```
with open('/Users/kyle/Documents/english words.txt') as word_file:
    english_words = set(word.strip().lower() for word in word_file if len(word.strip()) == 4)
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it, i will accept your answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks that makes it work great, how do i make it only display the words that are `true` or is this the wrong place to ask, i think that i should be asking on the "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf" site.

Comment: Use an `if` test? `if word in english: print word` instead of the current `print` statement? That is not exactly hard to do.

Comment: @kylek: But it'd be quicker just to print out my filtered `english_words` set instead of re-generating all possible 4-letter combinations. The set I generate at the end of my answer contains *all* 4 letter words that'll ever match your 4 letter combination loop.

Comment: Thanks that was a lot of help, all of the problems have been worked out and i have no further questions.